# Setting values -in a constructor- from another class

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, setter

I have two classes (Date and Employee).

Class Date doesn't have a constructor, but it has 3 variables with their setters.

Class Employee has a constructor where I initialized its variables. But I have to attach the 3 variables in Class Date to it.

I tried using Setter method, but when I run the code, it says that there's an error with:

```
hire_date.setDay(1);
hire_date.setMonth(1); 
hire_date.setYear(2018);
```

//In class Empolyee

```
 private String name;
 private Date hire_date;
 private double monthly_salary; 

    public Employee() {
        name = "Jody";
        hire_date.setDay(1);
        hire_date.setMonth(1); 
        hire_date.setYear(2018);         
        monthly_salary = 2000.0;
    }
```

//In class Date

```
 private int day;   
 private int month;
 private int year;

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you also said *which* error you are getting...

Comment: nullpointer, from the code

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: You need to initialize hire_date before calling setters of the variable. Try Date hire_date = new Date();

Comment: @chaitanya89 True. Thanks.

Comment: @daniu Why does the compiler give me an error?

Comment: @PaulJanssens True. Thanks

Comment: @assylias It is ((Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException)). I will consider this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not created a Date object. Therefore, how you should be able to set its properties?

```
Date hire_date = new Date();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new Date() missing. Your Date object does not exist when you invoke the setters

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I run this program.
Error in here is a *Null Pointer exception*.

Reason for it is that hire_date is not initialized. You need to add:
hire_date = new Date();

before first usage of hire_date